# How To Remove Characters from String based on Some Conditions

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements, procedure, pysimplegui

Dears,

How To Remove Characters from String based on Some Conditions ? Knowing that I have one string where I need to :

1. STEP 01 : Remeove vowels
2. STEP 02 : Remove Duplicate consonants and keep the 1st appeared one.
3. STEP 03 : Remove 1st and Last Characters if string starts/Ends with a given letter.

Example : Word : **Transmuted**

After Step01 ( Removing Vowels) =>  **Trnsmtd**
After Step02 ( Removing Duplicate Consnants , here "2nd t", "2nd n", "2nd s" ) ==> **Trnsmd**
After Step03 ( Removing 1st and Last Characters if word starts or ends with "t" and "d" => **rnsm**

Here is my first part of python Script , need the remaining 2 Steps:

```
string = "Transmuted"

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
result = ""

for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i] not in vowels:
    result = result + string[i]

    print("\nAfter removing Vowels: ", result)
```

**OUTPUT** : After removing Vowels:  Trnsmtd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another version of Step 01:

```
word = 'THERMOCHEMISTRY'

vowels={'a','e','i','o','u'}
result = ''.join([letter for letter in word if letter.lower() not in vowels])
```

For step 02, you could do this (there are probably more efficient methods, but this works):

```
result2 = ""
for i in result:
    if i.lower() not in result2 and i.upper() not in result2:
        result2 += i
```

For step 03

```
filter_out = {'d','t'}
result3 = result2[1:] if result2[0].lower() in filter_out else result2
result3 = result3[:-1] if result3[-1].lower() in filter_out else result3

print(result + ' '+result2+' '+result3)
# THRMCHMSTRY THRMCSY HRMCSY
```

Comment: Thanks @Swifty, same comment as above, need to keep those 1st /Last Letter if doens't meet condition:
THERMOCHEMISTRY
After removing Vowels:  THRMCHMSTRY
Final Result:  HRMCS

=> I should have HRMCSY at the end instead of HRMCS

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your goal; i'll rectify the code for step03. Meanwhile, I updated step02. Here, fixed

Comment: No issue. YES, Please.

Comment: Still there is an issue : example probably => gives : prbbly prbbly prbbly, it should be "prbly"

Comment: Oh indeed, I'll hunt this bug to death! That was a stupid oversight when I updated step02; I'll post the fix at once. All done, there should be no more bug (or I eat my hat).

Comment: After check , seems your hat is safe. Thanks a lot @Swifty, Working as desired. Thanks Martian for you too. Excellent JOB dears.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want step by step solution, check out this code:**

```
string_ = "Transmuted"

vowels_ = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
states_ = set()
filter_ = {'T', 'D'}

result_step1 = ""
for i in range(len(string_)):
    if string_[i] not in vowels_:
            result_step1 = result_step1 + string_[i]

print("\nAfter removing Vowels: ", result_step1)


result_step2 = ""
for i in range(len(result_step1)):
    if result_step1[i].upper() not in states_:
        result_step2 += result_step1[i]
        states_.add(result_step1[i].upper())
    
print("\nAfter removing Duplicate: ", result_step2)

start_ = 0 if result_step2[0].upper() not in filter_ else 1
end_ = len(result_step2)-1 if result_step2[0].upper() not in filter_ else len(result_step2)-2

result_step3 = result_step2[start_:end_]
print("\nAfter removing 1st and Last Char: ", result_step3)
```

OUPUT:

```
After removing Vowels:  Trnsmtd

After removing Duplicate:  Trnsmd

After removing 1st and Last Char:  rnsm
```

---

**And if you want final result you may refer to @Swifty code or this:**

```
string_ = "Transmuted"

vowels_ = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
states_ = {chr(i):0 for i in range(65, 91)}
result = ""

for i in range(len(string_)):
    if string_[i] not in vowels_:
        if states_[string_[i].upper()] < 1:
            result = result + string_[i]
            states_[string_[i].upper()] += 1

    print("\nAfter removing Vowels: ", result[1:len(result)-1])
```

Comment: Thanks @Martian for prompt feedback, but in Step3 , I need to remove 1st and last characters only if the condition met ( as an example, I want to remove them only if the letter is "t" or "d" . for example for word : THERMOCHEMISTRY I will get HRMCSY as it's starting with "t" only, the end is "y"

Comment: This : range(65, 91) stands for what ? unicode equivalent for "d" and "t". I've checked in : https://unicode-table.com/en/ not giving those values.